# How to recover wallet from Master Private Key?

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, litecoin, javascript

I've tried this approach to recover litecoin wallet, but it seem to print wrongly generated hashes (as I actually have wallet public and private keys for comparison), what can be wrong here? my wallet addresses doesn't have Lt prefix on address, I also didn't understand where to put derivation path so I left it hanging

[image: Code attempt to recover wallet from xprv]

Comment: Does this help? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/65295/5406

Answer (score 0):

Si has tenido antes una buena gestión en el riesgo de "de no olvidar las claves semillas" de seguro serás imparable en esto.